# Irfanview cannot extract file info

Tags: irfanview

Irfanview is one of the most useful tools in my arsenal. Today, suddenly, its behavior changed, and I cannot figure out what happened.
Problem 1, In a batch file that I have been using for more than ten years, I have the line.

```
"C:\Program Files\IrfanView\i_view64" *.tif  /info="irfanview_info.txt" /fullinfo
```

This command collects the information about all the image files in the directory.
Suddenly, the file "irfanview_info.txt came out void, in spite of having several hundred files in the directory.
After some trials, I ran the script as administrator, and it worked. However, it did not work against another directory, even with administrator privileges.

Does Irfanview have any error logging available?

Problem 2 Another problem that came out from nowhere was that on image opening; the image fitted the screen width. Even after changing the image width, in viewing a directory, the first image is opened according to the settings, but the next image is shown with full display width.

Probably the problems are unrelated, but they occurred at the same time.

Comment: >> Today, suddenly, its behavior changed ... did you apply an update? If so, perhaps that's the issue. IIRC, Irfanview.com lets you download earlier versions. That might be at least a temporary fix while  you track down the actual source of the problem.  Next, have you reported the problem to Irfan Skiljian (sp?), the author?  There are forums on the site (irfanview.com) or mail to irfanview@gmx.net